# Rust: nalgebra transpose

Tags: rust, nalgebra

I've started to practice rust.
I've run the program and got:

```
VecStorage { data: [1.0, 88.0, 87.0, 1.0, 70.0, 77.0, 1.0, 80.0, 79.0, 1.0, 82.0, 85.0, 1.0, 90.0, 97.0, 1.0, 100.0, 98.0], nrows: Dynamic { value: 6 }, ncols: Dynamic { value: 3 } }
VecStorage { data: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 88.0, 80.0, 90.0, 87.0, 79.0, 97.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 70.0, 82.0, 100.0, 77.0, 85.0, 98.0], nrows: Dynamic { value: 3 }, ncols: Dynamic { value: 6 } }
```

main.rs:

```
let matrix = vec![1.0,88.0,87.0,1.0,70.0,77.0,1.0,80.0,79.0,1.0,82.0,85.0,1.0,90.0,97.0,1.0,100.0,98.0];
    let matrix =  DMatrix::from_vec(6,3,matrix);
    println!("{:?}",matrix);
    println!("{:?}",matrix.transpose());
```

However transpose matrix is different(from the correct transpose), any ideas why?

Comment: The transpose matrix *should* be different from the original matrix, shouldn't it?

Comment: @BlackBeans it's not following the equation of transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/latest/nalgebra/base/struct.Matrix.html#method.from_vec-3), the matrix is filled from vector in column-major order. I suspect from the provided data that you're expecting a row-major one (with a first column of the original matrix holding only `1`s).

We can see this if we use `Display` formatting instead of `Debug` - the output in this case is the following:

```
  ┌             ┐
  │   1   1   1 │
  │  88  80  90 │
  │  87  79  97 │
  │   1   1   1 │
  │  70  82 100 │
  │  77  85  98 │
  └             ┘

  ┌                         ┐
  │   1  88  87   1  70  77 │
  │   1  80  79   1  82  85 │
  │   1  90  97   1 100  98 │
  └                         ┘
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae8fbe17d0e452149e81ac8df38bfd91)